# How to access apex data in HTML in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have below JS

```
@track proposalData = {};
    @wire(proposalDetails, { productConfigId: '$productConfigId' })
    proposalDetail({ data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.proposalData = data;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    }
```

and in console log I get exactly what is needed

> {"Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__c":"a3l6E000000BfKoQAK","Id":"a516E000000HdtqQAC","Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r":{"Name":"Q-00005178","Id":"a3l6E000000BfKoQAK"}}

but when I add the below in HTML I get an error

```
<template if:true={proposalData}>
      <p>from apex: {proposalData.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r.Name}</p>
  </template>
```

error

> [Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have already defined `proposalData` as a blank object.

```
@track proposalData = {};
```

As the wire is asynchronous, at the time Html is being rendered wire callout may be incomplete, as a result of that `proposalData.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r` is no present at that time.

So when you check,

```
<template if:true={proposalData}>
```

Which is true,

But when you try to access `{proposalData.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r.Name}` `proposalData.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r` might not be available yet.

So you can change your mark up as

```
<template if:true={proposalData.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r}>
    <p>from apex: {proposalData.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r.Name}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I am new to lwc, could you please be kind look into my other questions

Comment: Happy to help, happy coding!

Comment: here is the link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283201/navigation-is-not-working-in-lwc

Comment: and this is another one https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283181/using-related-parent-records-in-lwc

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code it may work for you

**JS**

```
@track proposalData;
@wire(proposalDetails, { productConfigId: '$productConfigId' })
proposalDetail({ data }) {
    if (data) {
    this.proposalData = {};
     console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        data.forEach(key => {
            this.proposalData.ApttusName = key.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__r.Name;
        })
    }
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<template if:true={proposalData}>
      <p>from apex: {proposalData.ApttusName}</p>
 </template>
```

Comment: can you point out what was the exact issue?

Comment: from the wire service data is getting in the array of Object you have to iterate the data assign that data to your predefined object.

Comment: Don't you think `this.proposalData.ApttusName` is getting overwritten on each iteration of forEach?

Comment: Thank you Shaik for your answer but there must be a better to achieve the same still I would appreciate your time and efforts.